# Срабатывает csrf защита если функция в отдельном js-файле

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, csrf

Всем привет,
В php/twig/JS проекте  нужно передать пару переменных csrf_token_name / csrf_token_hash  для выполения POST-запроса :

```
function save_bookmark_to_product() {
    var product_id= $("#hidden_bookmarks_to_product").val()
    var product_bookmark_info= $("#product_bookmark_info").val()
    var is_featured= $("#is_featured").is(':checked')
    var href= " base_url products/save_bookmark_to_product"
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: href,
        type: 'POST',
         data: { product_id : product_id, info : product_bookmark_info, is_featured : ( is_featured ? 'Y' : 'N' ), logged_user_id : ' LoggedUserId ',  csrf_token_name  : ' csrf_token_hash ' },
                dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(result) {
                    if (result.ErrorCode != 0) {
                        alert( result.ErrorMessage )
                    }
                    if (result.ErrorCode == 0) {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                }
            });

            }


    dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
        if (result.ErrorCode != 0) {
            alert( result.ErrorMessage )
        }
        if (result.ErrorCode == 0) {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
});

}
```

И в исходниках я вижу :

```
function save_bookmark_to_product() {
    var product_id= $("#hidden_bookmarks_to_product").val()
    var product_bookmark_info= $("#product_bookmark_info").val()
    var is_featured= $("#is_featured").is(':checked')
    var href= "http://local-wprods.com/products/save_bookmark_to_product"
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: href,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { product_id : product_id, info : product_bookmark_info, is_featured : ( is_featured ? 'Y' : 'N' ), logged_user_id : '1', csrf_test_name : '41033b3370643982ad5a33cc7e630a7d' },
    dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
        if (result.ErrorCode != 0) {
            alert( result.ErrorMessage )
        }
        if (result.ErrorCode == 0) {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
});

}
```

Код выше нормально работает.

Но я хочу вынести все функции в отдельный JS-файл и получаю ошибку.
В twig файле я определяю :

    //

```
var base_url= ' base_url '
var logged_user_id = ' LoggedUserId '
var csrf_token_name = ' csrf_token_name '
var csrf_token_hash= ' csrf_token_hash '
```

...

В отдельном file.js с ошибкой эти переменные находит:

```
 $(function() {
    ...
     alert( "frontend_app.jsbase_url:"+base_url + "  logged_user_id::"+logged_user_id+"  csrf_token_hash::"+csrf_token_hash)  — ВЫВОДЯТСЯ ПРАВИЛЬНЫЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ
    fancyBoxInit()
     if ( parseInt(logged_user_id) > 0 ) {
         getCartSummary()
     }
});



 function save_bookmark_to_product() {
     var product_id= $("#hidden_bookmarks_to_product").val()
     var product_bookmark_info= $("#product_bookmark_info").val()
     var is_featured= $("#is_featured").is(':checked')
     var href= " base_url products/save_bookmark_to_product"
     alert( "csrf_token_hash::"+csrf_token_hash )  // ВЫВОДИТ  csrf_token_hash::41033b3370643982ad5a33cc7e630a7d
     jQuery.ajax({
         url: href,
         type: 'POST',
         data: { product_id : product_id, info : product_bookmark_info, is_featured : ( is_featured ? 'Y' : 'N' ), logged_user_id : logged_user_id, csrf_token_name : csrf_token_hash },
     dataType: 'json',
         success: function(result) {
         if (result.ErrorCode != 0) {
             alert( result.ErrorMessage )
         }
         if (result.ErrorCode == 0) {
             location.reload();
         }
     }
 });

 }
```

Но получаю 403 ошибку

```
An Error Was Encountered
The action you have requested is not allowed.
```

Не понимаю почему во 2ом случае вызов из отдельного файла вызывает ошибку и в чем разница?

Так:

```
csrf_token_hash.toString()
```

Не помогает ...

Спасибо!

---

Урл правильный и бработка обрабатывает правильно(данные добавляются) если отключить csrf_protection в конфиге

Проблема начинается если js функцию save_bookmark_to_product вынести в отдельный js файл

и параметр csrf_token_hash - передать как параметр

`alert( "csrf_token_hash::"+csrf_token_hash + "  base_url::"+base_url )`  -- ВЫВОДИТ ПРАВИЛЬНЫЕ ПАРАМЕТРЫ

```
 jQuery.ajax({
     url: href,
     type: 'POST',
     data: { product_id : product_id, info : product_bookmark_info, is_featured : ( is_featured ? 'Y' : 'N' ), logged_user_id : logged_user_id, csrf_token_name : csrf_token_hash },
 dataType: 'json',
     success: function(result) {
     if (result.ErrorCode != 0) {
         alert( result.ErrorMessage )  -- получаю 403 ошибку


 }
 if (result.ErrorCode == 0) {
     location.reload();
 }
```

Как я писал изначально если save_bookmark_to_product расположена в twig-темплете

```
function save_bookmark_to_product() {
    var product_id= $("#hidden_bookmarks_to_product").val()
    var product_bookmark_info= $("#product_bookmark_info").val()
    var is_featured= $("#is_featured").is(':checked')
    var href= " base_url products/save_bookmark_to_product"
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: href,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { product_id : product_id, info : product_bookmark_info, is_featured : ( is_featured ? 'Y' : 'N' ), logged_user_id : ' LoggedUserId ',  csrf_token_name  : ' csrf_token_hash ' },
    dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
```

То срабатывает нормально Но хотелось js-функции вынести в отдельный js-файл и я не понимаю почему ошибка в этом случае.

Comment: base_url, csrf_token_hash, csrf_token_name,csrf_token_hash у вас с сервера приходят нормально? 403 Forbidden— сервер понял запрос, но он отказывается его выполнять из-за ограничений в доступе для клиента к указанному ресурсу. Возможно у вас урл неправильно сформирован.  Вы проверяли все параметры приходят правильно?

Comment: ещё нашёл http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214612/codeigniter-csrf-error-the-action-you-have-requested-is-not-allowed

Comment: Так выглядит запрос в хроме

http://imgur.com/a/ZR6Ed 
Все параметры на месте и как я писал что если в конфиге отключить csrf-защиту то срабатывает нормально

Я подгружаю свой файл frontend_app.js самым последним:

http://pastebin.com/TBtrMTK7

Может сделать загрузку как-то иначе ?

Comment: возможно у вас неправильно настроен mod_rewrite

Comment: попробуйте в конфиге поставить $config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;

Comment: $config['csrf_protection'] = true;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
И обьясните, плиз, как это может быть связано с mod_rewrite и какие должны быть настройки ?